# quick to setup version control that integrates well with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control

I've got to a point where i want to start using version control for my project.
Mainly for reverting to previous versions of files if things go belly up, doing diff comparisons. Nothing major.

I want something that integrates well with visual studio, and something thats relatively simple to setup. - prefereably with a link to a tutorial for setting up would be nice.

Im just using my pc for this so something like TFS is out of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVN together with free [AnkhSVN](http://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fankhsvn.open.collab.net%2F&ei=W5paTc7-BtCeOvOz5d0L&usg=AFQjCNGvStDS9dax4Ka96cs0i70nMKAjMg&sig2=q0WzRiPBM8FUBEYogWeAJw) Visual Studio plug-in.

And if you want to host the repository yourself, you can use [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/).

I use this combination and it works flawlessly.

Comment: Second VisualSVN. You do not even need the server if you create a local repository (from your question I understood you'll be the only one using it).

Comment: so install AnkhSVN and VisualSVN Server and i'm good to go? or is SVN a separate install I need to do too?

Comment: @raklos No, just VisualSVN server and AnkhSVN

Answer (score 1):

VisualSVN server is very easy to setup.  The VisualSVN server is free.  The client, however, is $49.   You don't have to use the VisualSVN client though.

You might want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453481/what-subversion-plugins-for-visual-studio-are-there) as well.